# Regex match characters not inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file containing custom code such as:

```
#include "folder/file.txt"
#include "folder with spaces/file.txt"
#include "$variable/file.txt"
#define $foo joe
#define $bar 34
```

I would like to extract the values from each line using a RegEx match. A JavaScript RegEx such as `[^#"\s]+` matches most values correctly, except for spaces inside quotes:

```
include
folder/file.txt
include
folder
with
spaces/file.txt
include
$variable/file.txt
define
$foo
joe
define
$bar
34
```

https://regex101.com/r/AmAh3T/1

I would like to ignore spaces within quotes so the list of matched values becomes:

```
include
folder/file.txt
include
folder with spaces/file.txt
include
$variable/file.txt
define
$foo
joe
define
$bar
34
```

I've tried using a lookahead to ignore spaces inside quotes `[^\s]+(?=(?:[^"]|["][^"]*["])*$)` but this ignores any string before a space inside quotes:

```
include
"folder/file.txt"
include
spaces/file.txt"
include
"$variable/file.txt"
define
$foo
joe
define
$bar
34
```

https://regex101.com/r/WbU0X2/2

How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: Try something like [`(?<=")[^\n"]*(?=")|[^#"\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/b1ay1a/1)

Comment: try this    /(?:include|define)\s+("[^"]*"|\S+)/g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider matching the regular expression

```
(?<=")[^#"]+(?=")|[^# \r\n"]+
```

with the `g` ("global", do not return after first match) flag set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tClvAW/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=")       # positive lookbehind asserts that the match is preceded
             # by a double quote
[^#"]+       # match one or more (`+`) characters other than (`^`) those
             # listed in the character class
(?=")        # positive lookahead asserts that the match is followed
             # by a double quote
|            # or
[^# \r\n"]+  # match one or more (`+`) characters other than (`^`) those
             # listed in the character class
```

Alternatively (or in addition), hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.